# Converting JSON to Excel using R

Tags: json, r, file-conversion, rjson, rjsonio

I'm new to R, and I'm practicing converting JSon to R, then to CSV or Excel. I downloaded the entire Magic the Gathering card set from: https://mtgjson.com/ to practice. I used this code to get it into a "list", but I'd like it in a dataframe or table.

```
   json_file<- rjson::fromJSON(file= "C://Users/ahalman/Desktop/AllCards.json")
```

I tried:

```
   as.data.frame(json_file)
```

but I get an error message that says: "Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 13, 10, 14, 15, 11, 12, 16, 19, 9, 8, 6, 7, 18, 4, 17, 21, 23, 20, 22"

I thought this would fix it, as I saw it on another Stack Overflow page, but whatever it does, it didn't work:

```
  json_file <- lapply(json_file, function(x) {
  x[sapply(x, is.null)] <- NA
  unlist(x)
  })
```

Any help would be great. Once it's in a dataframe format, I got this!

Comment: I'm actually working with this same data.  Unluckily for you, it's not a trivial thing to make it tabular.  My approach was creating two tables: one for the cards, the other for the sets.  It involves liberal usage of `lapply()` and `vapply()`.

Comment: @NathanWerth I think I figured it mostly out with my answer below.  Check it out. Just requires a bit of cleaning. I used the "stringi" package.

Comment: Seems like my work blocks mtgjson.com, so I'll have to try it when I get home.  And sorry for missing the part where you're only dealing with the cards data.

Comment: All good, so it looks like the code worked for the first few columns, then I start getting weird results.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer:

```
  df<- stringi::stri_list2matrix(json_file, byrow = TRUE)
```

This works for the first few columns, but things start to get jumbled. No idea why.

I think I finally figure it out:

```
 newdf<- stringi::stri_list2matrix(json_file, byrow = TRUE, fill = "")
```